# Generating all permutations from a list of positional substitutions for a given string

Tags: python, string, permutation

I'm a Python beginner and am trying to figure out the best way to approach the following problem:

For a given string, e.g. a = 'abcdefg', and a given list, e.g. ['b2c', 'c3d', 'd4e'), I'd like to make all possible permutations of the substitutions of the string with the positions from the list.  Each item in the list denotes the current string for that position followed by what the substitution should be. For example, single substitutions would be:

```
b2c = 'accdefg'
c3d = 'abddefg'
d4e = 'abceefg'
```

I'd also like the combinatorial, such as:

```
b2c_c3d = 'acddefg'
b2c_d4e = 'acceefg'
c3d_d4e = 'abdeefg'
b2c_c3d_d4e = 'acdeefg'
```

Would itertools be able to do something like this?

The substitutions seem simple enough -- I was just going to use indexes to make changes in those positions of the string.

e.g for b2c -> b2c = a[:1] + 'c' + a[2:]

What I'm struggling with is how to generate all possible permutations for a given list aside from just brute forcing it.

Comment: Does the string in the list all look like "x" + "number" + "y" (x=a, number=2, y=c, then the string is "b2c")?

Answer (score 0):

Itertools' combinations() function can be used to get the power set  (not permutations) of your list of x#y replacement codes:

```
from itertools import combinations

a = 'abcdefg'
r = ['b2c', 'c3d', 'd4e']

for size in range(len(r)):
    for combo in combinations(r,size+1):
        s = list(a)
        for _,p,c in combo:
            s[int(p)-1] = c
        print("_".join(combo),"=","".join(s))

b2c = accdefg
c3d = abddefg
d4e = abceefg
b2c_c3d = acddefg
b2c_d4e = acceefg
c3d_d4e = abdeefg
b2c_c3d_d4e = acdeefg
```

*Note: The first letter in your replacement codes is not checked against the content of `a` nor is the position validated against the length of `a`. If you need to exclude replacement codes with non-matching letters / positions, you should do so outside of the loop so that only valid codes are combined.  If you validate/exclude the replacement codes after combining them, there will be a lot of wasted iterations (exponentially).*

For example (filtering out invalid replacement codes from `r`):

```
r = [c for c in r if int(c[1]) <= len(a) and a[int(c[1])-1]==c[0]]
```